# Do we have to answer Adhan on a personal clock like we're supposed to respond the real Adhan?

Tags: adhan

These days Muslims living in Western countries hear Adhan on special Adhan clocks at home 5 times a day. Is it permitted in Islam to set Adhan in a clock and listen to it? And also my real question is do we have to answer that Adhan like we're supposed to respond the real Adhan?